# Rails 3 Devise, Everything routes to localhost index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So I followed the Railscasts tutorials, and everything works up until I click submit on my sign up form. It gave me a root error which I then researched and found that the answer is there is no route. So I used root :to => 'home#index' in my routes file, which then allowed me to sign up and then get relocated to the index, but now when I try to access the sign up or login, I get the index page.

Here is my routes.rb file

```
Travel::Application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users
root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not still logged in? Maybe clear your cache or try a different browser. Your routes.rb file looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can't access the sign up or login pages while already logged in.  Try accessing `/users/sign_out` first.

Comment: It says there is No route matches "/users/sign_out"

Comment: If you clear your cookies, are you able to access the sign up & login pages again?

Comment: when I clear my cookies I can, but once I try to register another account, it does the same thing.

Comment: So then devise is behaving correctly for you.  Once you register/log in, you can't access the register/login page again until your session ends.  Accessing the sign out page or clearing your cookies will expire your session.  In order to find out the path to your sign out URL, run `rake routes | grep user` from your console to list all user-related paths.

Comment: your right. How can I have it route after the sign up is registered to go to the sign in page instead of automatically signing into a session?

Comment: It doesn't look like you can unless you modify the devise plugin or extend `Devise::RegistrationsController` in your app.  Take a look at [line 19](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L19) of that file, and you'll see that it's automatically signing users in after creating the user record.

Comment: I see what you mean. How can I change the route file though to a members homepage instead of the actual homepage. would that mean I would change 'home#index' to say 'home#member'?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in) on the Devise Wiki.  There are a bunch of helpful answers there to get you started too.